# python preg_replace translate message to gsm formatted message

Tags: python, regex

i am trying to to make a replace in order to send a gsm message later. i use the function below where it takes the message as parameter and convert it to a gsm formatted message.

```
import re
     @staticmethod
        def gsm_message(message):

            expressions = {
                '/[άΆαΑ]/u': 'A',
                '/[βΒ]/u': 'B',
                '/[έΈεΕ]/u': 'E',
                ......... more
            }

            translated_message = re.sub(expressions.keys(), expressions.values(), message)

            print(translated_message)
```

the error i get when i am trying to print is: unhashable type: 'list'.

what can i do to make it work?

Comment: maybe i am wrong in my title..i just described what i want to do so maybe i am doing wrong..i am not sure..i search for preg_replace in google and i found that re.sub so i use that cause i thought is the same as preg_replace..have you some idea how it works?

Comment: i am coming from php that's the reason i wrote it in this way. so, how is the correct syntax for my code in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works in Python3.

```
import re

def gsm_message(message):
    expressions = {
        'ά': 'A',
        'Ά': 'A',
        'α': 'A',
        'Α': 'A',
        'β': 'B',
        'Β': 'B',
        'έ': 'E',
        'Έ': 'E',
        'ε': 'E',
        'Ε': 'E',
    }
    pattern = re.compile('|'.join(expressions.keys()))
    translated_message = pattern.sub(lambda x: expressions[x.group()], message)
    print(translated_message)

message = "ββααέ"
gsm_message(message)
```

Gives:

```
BBAAE
```